# SQL select greater date when comparing multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that I'm working with that looks something like this:

```
Code    Name           Date
-------------------------------------------
10      General Fund   7/18/2013 1:36:15 PM     
100     Plain Fund     12/31/2099               
10300   Fund Name      8/12/2099                
10300   Fund Name      5/17/2099      
10300   Fund Name      12/31/2099
```

Some rows are identical except for their date - I want to select all the codes by the row with their greatest date, like so:

```
Code    Name           Date
-------------------------------------------
10      General Fund   7/18/2013 1:36:15 PM     
100     Plain Fund     12/31/2099                     
10300   Fund Name      12/31/2099
```

Here's what I have so far but it doesn't give me the desired result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.code, 
    t1.name, 
    t1.date, 
FROM table.fund t1
    INNER JOIN table.fund t2
    ON t1.code = t2.code
        AND TRUNC(t1.date) > TRUNC(t2.date);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select code, name, max(date) from your_table group by code, name;
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I was overthinking things apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use windowed functions to accomplish this:

```
select
*
from
(
  select
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "TheName" ORDER BY "TheDate" desc) as RN,
  fund.*
  from 
  fund
) t
where t.RN = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29fe2/2)

Comment: PARTITION BY is specific to Oracle, isn't it?

Comment: PARTITION BY isn't specific to Oracle, but your answer is better.

Comment: No, that's ANSI SQL, as far as I know.  And his question is tagged as Oracle anyhow.

Comment: Ooh, having re-read the question, I made this way too hard, assuming all other columns are in fact identical.

Comment: That's right, I missed the tag. ANSI SQL 99 to be precise. Sorry about the mess.